# Why does dpkg - l not show me the same tools as the Kali Linux tool listing (https://tools.kali.org/tools-listing)

Tags: linux, debian

Why does dpkg - l not show me the same tools as the Kali Linux tool listing https://tools.kali.org/tools-listing

What am I missing? I ran dpkg -l and tried to grep for a tool I know is installed on my Kali Linux distro. But it does not show up.

is there a command that captures all the installed tools in kali linux ??

Comment: I run it and it shows me a list (over 400 lines).  What version of Kali? I am on 2021.1

Comment: Why don't you try the other way round? If `tool` is installed in `/usr/bin/tool`, try `dpkg -S /usr/bin/tool` and see if it belongs to a package; or try it like `dpkg -S \`which tool\``. This should tell you which package installed `tool` and maybe give you a hint as to where you should turn your attention.

Comment: John, run a test, try  dpkg -l | grep -i "Enum4linux"

Comment: Tried dpkg -S 'enum4linux' , did not find it either. But i just ran enum4linux successfully

Answer (score 0):

ok, so not every application installed in Kali linux is available by running dpkg -l.
the best thing to run is find / -name "application name". Some packages are installed by git cloning the package rather than installing via apt-get.

Comment: That makes sense. You can also go slumming through all the directories listed in your PATH environment variable because that's where Linux looks for anything you tell it to execute without giving it an explicit path.

Comment: Thank's @Joe :)